# Finding upper bounds of a set

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Suppose $A = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x + \frac{1}{x} < 5 \} $. I want to find 2 upper bounds of $A$. My intuition tells me that $5$ is indeed an upper bound. To see this, I want to show that for every $x \in A $, we have $x \leq 5 $. Suppose not: there is $y \in A$ with $y > 5 $. But

$$ 5 > y + \frac{1}{y} > 5 + \frac{1}{y} \implies 0 > \frac{1}{y}$$

which is a contradiction. Hence, $5$ is an upper bound. Moreover, $6$ must also be an upper bound.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct.  To get the best bound, you could try solving $x+1/x=5$.